# Printer works from VS 2010 on virtual machine, but does not work correct from VS 2012, why?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, windows-7, printing, virtual-machine

I am developing a little WPF app printing out labels.

I am using Dymo LabelWriter 400. It's connected to my computer by USB.
http://global.dymo.com/ieIE/Products/LabelWriter_400.html

I am printing out labels, but I only get half of the label out. It's a very clean cut half.
Exactly the same problem as here:
http://www.justanswer.com/printers/6bpe9-label-writer-400-turbo-printing-half-label.html

I have installed what I understand as the appropriate driver for this printer:
"NEW DYMO Label Software Application Version 8.5 for Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7 and Windows 8 ONLY"
https://dymo.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/101/~/dymo-drivers-and-downloads

I have two development environments, one live on a virtual machine. It's VMware Workstation.

The other development environment lives just on my host machine.

On the virtual machine I am using Visual Studio 2010 Professional IDE. And I am using Windows 7 professional in English.

On my host machine I am using Visual Studio 2012 Professional IDE, and I am using Windows 7 professional with Danish language settings.

The funny thing is that when I run my app in the Visual Studio 2010 IDE on the Virtual Machine the labels print out totally OK. I can see that the printer name here is: "DYMO LabelWriter 400#:7"

But when I run the same app in the Visual Studio 2012 IDE on my host machine, I only get half the label. I can see that the printer name here is "DYMO LabelWriter 400"

Any idea why I can't print out correct labels in the Visual Studio 2012 environment?

Where as I have no problems printing out from the same app in the Visual Studio 2010 environment on the virtual machine?

Perhaps I should ask this question somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem.
I am slightly embarassed by the solution.
The solution was to adjust the size of the label template, which was done in "Advanced" under printer settings. After having done that I could enjoy my labels printed out in full size :) I never found out why there was a difference in the printer settings from the host machine to the virtual machine. I thought the settings would be the same. But never mind, now it works.